# Python dictionary ordering and printing

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a file with mountains and their height and their mountains ranges. I have to extract from the csv file containing these data, the mountains ranges which each heights (as there is fewer mountains for each ranges in the csv), and I also have to count how many time each range appears. Then my program should print the 2 first mountain ranges and their heights

Here the guidelines :

> Rewrite your function to use the collections module's Counter to count how many times each mountain range is mentioned. Each row contains a mountain, its height, and the range it is part of. The ranges are still in the 3rd column of the mountains.csv file!  You can use more than one function if you want.

```
        with open('mountains.csv', 'r') as handle:
            for line in handle:

Shishapangma,8027,Himalayas,
```

Comment: don't post the link to the data but edit your post to include a sample of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify your code as little as possible based on the other comments. This should achieve what you are looking for using your existing function/code.

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

def mountain_ranges(filename):
    ranges = Counter()
    heights = defaultdict(list)  
    msg = "The average height of {} is {} meters."
    err_msg = "Error: File doesn't exist or is unreadable."
    dictionary = {}

    try:
        with open('mountains.csv', 'r') as handle:
            for line in handle:
                mnt, height, range_, _ = line.strip().split(',')
                ranges[range_] += 1
                heights[range_].append(int(height))

    except IOError:
        print(err_msg)
    print("The two most common ranges are:\n")
    print([r[0] for r in ranges.most_common(2)])

    for range_ in heights:
        print(msg.format(range_, mean(heights[range_])))
```

Comment: no it's not part of the csv module, I updated the code, it looks like each row actually has 4 columns, not 3 because you have a trailing comma. the code reflects that now

Comment: as of Python 3.6 dictionaries are ordered by _default_

Comment: Just with another data set it seems to not working, I have this issue :

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Any idea ?

Comment: seems that the other data set only has 3 values, which means this line `mnt, height, range_, _ = line.strip().split(',')` should become `mnt, height, range_ = line.strip().split(',')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212570/discussion-between-arthur-guyart-and-gold-cy).

Comment: I need to use the same code for the both file :/ any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You add all key/value -pairs in dictionary to your ranges and heights variables every time you handle a line in csv file.

Try like this:

```py
with open('mountains.csv', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        key = line.replace('"', '').strip()
        k = key.split(",")
        # You always overwrited value here...
        # dictionary[k[2]] = k[1]
        if k[2] not in dictionary:
             dictionary[k[2]] = []
        dictionary[k[2]].append(k[1])
    # moved these loops out of upper for-loop
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        ranges[key] += 1  
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        heights[key].append(value)
```

And to get rid of that check if key exists use `defaultdict` from `collections`

Comment: Oh yes. I see the problem. Wait a minut.

Comment: What you mean by adding part?

Comment: Add each values in the data to the list (like in the assert)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read data like this. Since order is meaningful, use a list:

```
import csv
with open('mountains.csv') as f:
    data=[[mtn,int(height),range] for (mtn,height,range,_) in csv.reader(f)]

# the extra _ is because you have an extra blank field in your example 
# from the trailing ,
```

Or, if you cannot use csv, in this simple case, you can replicate the function like this:

```
with open('mountain.csv') as f:
    data=[[mtn,int(height),rng] 
             for (mtn,height,rng,_) in (line.split(',') for line in f)]
```

That is it! Then you have the data needed to answer all other questions:

```
print(data)

[['Mount Everest', 8848, 'Himalayas'], ['K2', 8611, 'Karakoram'], 
 ['Kangchenjunga', 8586, 'Himalayas'], ['Lhotse', 8516, 'Himalayas'], 
 ['Makalu', 8485, 'Himalayas'], ['Cho Oyu', 8201, 'Himalayas'], 
 ['Dhaulagiri', 8167, 'Himalayas'], ['Manaslu', 8163, 'Himalayas'], 
 ['Nanga Parbat', 8126, 'Himalayas'], ['Annapurna', 8091, 'Himalayas'], 
 ['Gasherbrum I', 8080, 'Karakoram'], ['Broad Peak', 8051, 'Karakoram'], 
 ['Gasherbrum II', 8035, 'Karakoram'], ['Shishapangma', 8027, 'Himalayas']]

from collections import Counter 
print(Counter(row[2] for row in data))

# prints Counter({'Himalayas': 10, 'Karakoram': 4})

print(f'Average height of all mountains: {sum(row[1] for row in data)/len(data)}')

# prints "Average height of all mountains: 8284.785714285714"
```

And by range:

```
for rng, cnt in (Counter(row[2] for row in data).items()):
    print(f'Average for {rng}: {sum(row[1] for row in data if row[2]==rng)/cnt}')
```

Prints:

```
Average for Himalayas: 8321.0
Average for Karakoram: 8194.25
```

Comment: I totally agree with you, it would clearly be more easier... However, as that's the beginner level, they do not introduce the csv module yet... So pretty stuck with the other version for now :/

Comment: Yes, I agree. There would be much more straightforward and effective approaches to this problem. But because this is homework, it is better to help one to make his own code work and understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from statistics import mean   # this also exists in numpy if you prefer
# define your dicts inside the function, so they can be re-used each time it is called.


def mountain_ranges(filename):
    ranges = Counter()
    heights = defaultdict(list)
    msg = "The height of {} is {} meters."
    err_msg = "Error: File doesn't exist or is unreadable."
    dictionary = {}

    temp_list = []
    try:
        with open('mountains.csv', 'r') as handle:


            for row in handle:
                temp_list.append(row.split(','))

            for item in temp_list:
                    ranges[item[2].rstrip()] += 1  
                    heights[item[2].rstrip()].append(item[1]) 


    except IOError:
        print(err_msg)
    ranges = OrderedDict(ranges.most_common(2))
    print(ranges)
    print(heights)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Himalayas', 10), ('Karakoram', 4)])
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Himalayas': ['8848', '8586', '8516', '8485', '8201', '8167', '8163', '8126', '8091', '8027'], 'Karakoram': ['8611', '8080', '8051', '8035']})
```